# SP2013 - 50 item limit on search results

Tags: 2013, search-results

I am using a search result web part and it will only return a maximum of 50 items per page. There is no facility in the web part to increase it beyond 50.

I have read that this value is hard wired somewhere. Does anybody have any idea as to how to solve this?

The same behavior is visible on the default search results pages too.

Comment: yes I am sure otherwise I wouldn't see more than 1 page!!

Answer (score 7):

Christopher,

[Change how search results appear in the Search Core Results Web Part](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg549981.aspx)

Excerpt from the article:

> **Change the number of results that appear on a page** 
>   Under Display Properties, in the Results Per Page box, type the number of results
>   that you want to appear on a page before pagination is required. The
>   maximum is 50 results. The default is 10 results. Increasing this
>   number affects how quickly the user interface renders.

Comment: Doesn't this just allow me to change the limit to a maximum of 50...?

Comment: It should, but its not maximum number of items PER PAGE.. From your question it seems you talking about total results?

Comment: I want to remove the 50 items limit so that I can display 500 or whatever items per page....

Comment: @ChristopherC.D.Wells you shouldn't as the MSDN documentation mentions.. Increasing this number affects how quickly the user interface renders.. if you will increase the items the page will render slowly, thus 50 items per page should be the max!

Comment: yes I am aware of what the documentations says - but with display templates that limit becomes immaterial if you are only rendering one or two words per item.

Answer (score 4):

I found a workaround to this limitation and have blogged about it here:   http://www.scottewing.net/Blog/Post/2/Getting-Around-the-Content-Search-Web-Part%27s-50-Results-Limit

Since the Search Results web part uses the ResultScriptWebPart class, the solution is very similar.  It requires writing server-side code using reflection and deploying a farm solution, so if you don't have that option then you may be stuck.  There's also a client-side solution here but it doesn't work for anonymous access:   http://sharepoint-community.net/forum/topics/how-to-override-content-by-search-web-part-s-limit-of-50-results

Disclaimer: In most cases I'd agree that you shouldn't show more than 50 results on a page.  However, I believe there are almost always exceptions to every rule.  In my case, I needed to go over this limit because we were porting a WordPress site over that had a page that needed this, and we needed it to behave the same way.

Comment: your first link gives very clear answer to the problem. They have implemented and tested them. Helped me so much. Thank you!